Dirac strings are classically observable through induction?
For my Masterthesis I will have to dive a bit into Dirac monopoles, which are said to be pairwise connected by a Dirac string which is just an infinitesimal fiber carrying magnetic flux $|\vec{B}|=g$. Now if the pole crosses an induction coil there must be an inductive component from the fiber, $V= \frac{d\Phi_{string}}{dt}$ where the flux $\Phi_{string}(t)$ would be the integral $\int{\vec{B}(t)d\vec{S}}$ over the coil which we can simply set to be the step function $\Phi_{string}(t)=g \cdot \theta(t)$.
I can provide more details but I already found two papers (including 1982 Valentine's Monopole) that make predictions naturally assuming the inductive component from the string. But didn't we say the string is NOT observable? I feel like this paper has less in common with Dirac, just need to be sure that they stand in contradiction.


There is reference to observable Dirac strings (10.1142/S0217732308024316) when the Dirac condition is discarded, which is the case for my solid-state monopoles, not having "fundamental" magnetic charge.

Another point to remark is that this is a Dirac string changing over time.
